# How to track the progress of a volley request

Tags: android, android-volley, android-progressbar

I have been using volley networking library for some time now. To show the users that their request is being sent, I show them an indeterminate progress bar which I hide either in`onResponse` or `onErrorResponse`.

Bot now, I want to show the users the progress of the request and update the progress of the progress bar. In essence, I don't want to use an indeterminate again.

Say I am making this request:

```
/ Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://www.google.com";
//Show progressBar here

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        //I Hide progressBar here, and parse and display the response.
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        //I Hide progressBar here also and show a dialog to retry.
    }
});
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

How can I update the progress of the progressBar?

Comment: What type of progress? A stream of data isn't being sent, just a single, finished result. Therefore, I'm not sure you can "divide" the progress of it.

Comment: @cricket_007 but it can be done with asyncTask, right?

Comment: Again, depends how you define "progress". Yes, there is the `publishProgress` method in an AsyncTask, but if needed, that could be added to an extension of the `Request` class of Volley

Comment: @cricket_007 I thought the response of a Volley request is gotten in bytes until it's complete. What I mean by progress is say 20/2500 bytes complete, 50/2500, 250/2500, 600/2500 etc, you get mean? please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: That does make sense. You'd have to dig into the volley source code to "intercept" how much data is transferred. For example, looking at the `parseNetworkResponse` method, you'd need to calculate the length of the string, then estimate how much of it has been processed.  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/StringRequest.java

Comment: @cricket_007 in `parseNetworkResponse` just as the name implies, the response has been gotten already, right? So except I am wrong updating a progressBar for an already complete request is pretty useless. I was thinking something like when you are downloading a file, you can see the progress of the download until it's complete.

Comment: @Ozuuf did u find any solution?

Comment: @BhavinPatel, No I did not